# Как конвертировать строку в класс?

Tags: python, сокет

У меня есть строка, которая выглядит как класс `socket.socket`, но т.к это строка, она не имеет атрибута.

```
print(type(x)

<class 'str'>
```

**При выводе объекта:**

```
<class 'socket.socket'>
```

Дело в том, что до этого я сохранил объект как строку, а теперь надо конвертировать обратно в объект, чтобы выполнить функцию `send(из socket)`.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Как же выглядит строка, которая выглядит как класс? Даже интересно стало.

Comment: @Эникейщик возможно я не так написал. Я начал прослушку с помощью conn, addr = sock.accept(). Объект conn я сохранил как строку, а теперь мне нужно выполнить действие с отправкой

Comment: Так что у вас в `x`, как это выглядит, если напечатать?

Comment: @CrazyElf <socket.socket fd=6, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('', 6666), raddr=('', 43972)>

Comment: Ну взять каждое свойство и создать объект вручную...

Comment: @Эникейщик у объекта нет некоторых свойств, а именно laddr, raddr. Как тогда создать?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по твоему вопросу ты не знаешь основ ООП. Да, ты можешь распарсить строку до socket.socket:
`name = str(type(x))[8:2]`
Можешь импортировать функцию:
`from importlib import import_module as im im(name.split('.')[0])`
И можешь вызвать метод с exec:
`exec(f'newClass = {name}()')`
Но по этой строке нельзя узнать какие данные ты скормил конструктору, и как класс в процессе поменялся, это будет новый экземпляр класса. Точная копия будет затруднительна, но в теории возможна, запакуй инфу о классе в строку, если хочешь, методы атрибуты и тд, и потом распарсь.